# Can I place a .tsv file within a vectr in R?

Tags: r, csv

I want to read a tsv file with a lot of numbers. Is it possible to put it inside a vector?
Like, now I can manually place numbers in my vector, but can I just put the file inside the vector, so i takes all the values from the file?

```
my_vector <- c(1, 3, 7, 2, 6)
```

My idea was that I could write something like

```
my_vector <- c("my_file.tsv")
```

But it doesn't work. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You should be able to use `scan("my_file.tsv")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
unname(unlist(read.table("temp.tsv", sep="\t")))
```

Comment: Thank you! Why is it that my vector is now defined as "x"? Can I change that?

Comment: Just use something like `MyVector = unname(unlist(read.table("temp.tsv", sep="\t"

)))`